# Sorting in XQuery: Nested FLWOR

Tags: xml, nested, xquery, parent, flwor

I am trying to sort an XML document using XQuery. First level sorting is by one of the parent element.

And the second level sorting is one of the linked child element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FEATURES xmlns="http://www.example.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <FEATURE>
        <abbreviation>CANAL</abbreviation>
        <LINKED_PROPERTIES>
            <LP>
                <abbreviation>zltinf</abbreviation>
                <category>A</category>
                <remarks />
            </LP>
            <LP>
                <abbreviation>altalt</abbreviation>
                <category>A</category>
                <remarks />
            </LP>
            <LP>
                <abbreviation>betbet</abbreviation>
                <category>C</category>
                <remarks />
            </LP>
        </LINKED_PROPERTIES>
        <description>Water Canal</description>
        <code>23</code>
        <relation_type />
    </FEATURE>
    <FEATURE>
        <abbreviation>AREA</abbreviation>
        <LINKED_PROPERTIES>
            <LP>
                <abbreviation>zltzlt</abbreviation>
                <category>A</category>
                <remarks>zolt zolt</remarks>
            </LP>
            <LP>
                <abbreviation>altalt</abbreviation>
                <category>A</category>
                <remarks />
            </LP>
            <LP>
                <abbreviation>betbet</abbreviation>
                <category>C</category>
                <remarks />
            </LP>
        </LINKED_PROPERTIES>
        <description>Area under administration</description>
        <code>1</code>
        <relation_type />
    </FEATURE>
    <FEATURE>
        <abbreviation>BUOY</abbreviation>
        <LINKED_PROPERTIES>
            <LP>
                <abbreviation>zltinf</abbreviation>
                <category>A</category>
                <remarks />
            </LP>
            <LP>
                <abbreviation>altalt</abbreviation>
                <category>A</category>
                <remarks />
            </LP>
            <LP>
                <abbreviation>betbet</abbreviation>
                <category>C</category>
                <remarks />
            </LP>
            <LP>
                <abbreviation>infinf</abbreviation>
                <category>A</category>
                <remarks />
            </LP>
            <LP>
                <abbreviation>altalt</abbreviation>
                <category>A</category>
                <remarks />
            </LP>
            <LP>
                <abbreviation>betbet</abbreviation>
                <category>C</category>
                <remarks />
            </LP>
        </LINKED_PROPERTIES>
        <description>Buoy on water</description>
        <code>18</code>
        <relation_type />
    </FEATURE>
    <FEATURE>
        <abbreviation>DRONE</abbreviation>
        <LINKED_PROPERTIES>
            <LP>
                <abbreviation>zltinf</abbreviation>
                <category>A</category>
                <remarks />
            </LP>
            <LP>
                <abbreviation>beltam</abbreviation>
                <category>A</category>
                <remarks />
            </LP>
            <LP>
                <abbreviation>betbet</abbreviation>
                <category>C</category>
                <remarks />
            </LP>
        </LINKED_PROPERTIES>
        <description>Drones Inland</description>
        <code>2</code>
        <relation_type />
    </FEATURE>
</FEATURES>
```

This document contains features of two levels, which belongs to a standard. So obviously I cannot modify the XML document. Above data is anonymized data.

My XQuery is like the below.

```
<FEATURES xmlns="http://www.example.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    {
    let $doc := doc("features.xml")
    for $feature in $doc/FEATURES/FEATURE
    order by $feature/abbreviation ascending
    return
    <FEATURE>
        {
        for $ft in $feature
        return if ($ft/child::element/name() eq
        "LINKED_PROPERTIES")then
        <LINKED_PROPERTIES_XXXXXXXX>{
            for $lp in $ft/LINKED_PROPERTIES/LP
            order
            by $lp/abbreviation ascending
            return $lp
            }
        </LINKED_PROPERTIES_XXXXXXXX>
        else $ft/*}
    </FEATURE>
    }
</FEATURES>
```

I am unable to get the proper equality condition at the child level and hence not getting desired sorting at the child level.

I do not want to go back to DOM/XSL for several reasons. Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner `for` needs to iterate on the children of the feature, otherwise there will be only one item to iterate on. Also, further down in the tree, `LINKED_PROPERTIES` must be removed as $ft is already at that node, and other children must be returned as they are. Finally, the kind test was not quite right (must be `child::element()`).

```
<FEATURES xmlns="http://www.example.com/"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">{
  let $doc := doc("features.xml")
  for $feature in $doc/FEATURES/FEATURE
  order by $feature/abbreviation ascending
  return <FEATURE>{
    for $ft-child in $feature/child::element()
    return if ($ft-child/name() eq "LINKED_PROPERTIES")
           then <LINKED_PROPERTIES_XXXXXXXX>{
             for $lp in $ft-child/LP
             order by $lp/abbreviation ascending
             return $lp
            }</LINKED_PROPERTIES_XXXXXXXX>
            else $ft-child
  }</FEATURE>
}</FEATURES>
```

The above query succeeds in oXygen.

Comment: I tried BaseH as I do not have Oxygen. What I observed is mixing of parent feature elements with child Linked properties after running the xquery..

Comment: XQuery is standardized, it should work with BaseX as well. Feel free to paste your query and output if there is still something wrong, as well as your expected output. We'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to test if `FEATURE` has chid element `LINKED_PROPERTIES` :

```
return if ($ft/LINKED_PROPERTIES) then 
    <LINKED_PROPERTIES_XXXXXXXX>
    {
        .....
    }
    </LINKED_PROPERTIES_XXXXXXXX>
```

Your XQuery attempt for the same doesn't make much sense, it will never evaluates to true since it looks for child element named `element` (`$ft/child::element`) and further test if the element name equals `"LINKED_PROPERTIES"` (`/name() eq "LINKED_PROPERTIES"`).